# SVG Draw Path and Fill with Elliptical Arc

Tags: javascript, svg, ellipse

I am trying to progressively fill an ellipse behind a rotating radius, really, a clock-like timer that fills behind the sweeping hand. I am close to getting it right but the arc of the filled area moves with each recalculation.

The CodePen version is [here](http://codepen.io/mrthnmn/pen/PWZjZP) but to summarize, I am using the following HTML to start:

```
<svg version="1.1" baseProfile="full" width="50%" height="50%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 3 3.2">
  <path id="pie" stroke="none" stroke-width=".01" fill="rgb(204, 50, 50)"
          d="M 1.5 1.7 V 1.5 .3 
             A 1.5 1.3 0 0 1 1.5 .2
             z"/>
  <line id="hand" stroke="black" stroke-width=".02"
           x1="1.5" y1="1.7" x2="1.5" y2=".2"/>
</svg>
```

and the following JavaScript to rotate the hand and draw/fill behind it:

```
var sweep = document.getElementById("hand"),
    fill = document.getElementById("pie"),
    degrees = 0;
const Torads = Math.PI/180;

function rotateHand() {
  degrees += 45;
  sweep.setAttribute("transform", "rotate(" + degrees + " 1.5 1.7)");
  if (degrees <= 180) {
  fill.setAttribute("d", "M 1.5 1.7 V .4 A 1.4 1.3 0 0 1 " + ellipticalXcoords(Math.cos((degrees-90) * Torads)) + " " + ellipticalYcoords(Math.sin((degrees-90) * Torads)) + " z");
  } else {
  fill.setAttribute("d", "M 1.5 1.7 V .4 A 1.4 1.3 0 1 1 " + ellipticalXcoords(Math.cos((degrees - 90) * Torads)) + " " + ellipticalYcoords(Math.sin((degrees - 90) * Torads)) + " z");
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're making life quite difficult for yourself here. Instead of trying to calculate the incremental changes in the shape of the filled region, you could use the same shape as a clip mask applied to a regular circle that can be animated much more easily using the [`stroke-dasharray` trick](https://css-tricks.com/svg-line-animation-works/).

Here's how I would do it. Notice that the circular fill is rotated by -90° so that the animation starts at the top of the circle instead of the side. A corresponding +90° rotation is applied to the clip mask to account for this.

```js
var sweep = document.getElementById("hand"),
  fill = document.getElementById("apple-fill"),
  degrees = 0;
const Torads = Math.PI / 180;
var animating = false;

function rotateHand() {
  degrees += 4;
  if (degrees >= 360) {
    clearInterval(animating);
    animating = false;
    degrees = 360;
  }
  sweep.setAttribute("transform", "rotate(" + degrees + " 1.5 1.7)");
  fill.setAttribute("stroke-dasharray", degrees * 0.01309 + ", 20");
}

function startAnimation() {
  if (!animating) {
    degrees = 0;
    animating = setInterval(rotateHand, 30);
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="startAnimation(); return 0">Animate</button>
<svg width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 3 3.2">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="apple">
      <path d="M1.5.5A.2.2 0 0 1 1.7.315A1.4 1.3 0 1 1 1.3.315A.2.2 0 0 1 1.5.5z" transform="rotate(90,1.5,1.7)" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <circle cx="1.5" cy="1.7" r=".75" id="apple-fill" fill="none" stroke="rgb(204, 50, 50)" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-dasharray="0,20" transform="rotate(-90,1.5,1.7)" clip-path="url(#apple)" />
  <path id="pomodoro" stroke-width=".01" fill="none" stroke="#000" d="M1.5.5A.2.2 0 0 1 1.7.315A1.4 1.3 0 1 1 1.3.315A.2.2 0 0 1 1.5.5" />
  <path id="leaf" stroke-width=".01" stroke-linejoin="arc" fill="green" d="M1.5.6A.4.4 0 0 1 2 .1A.5.5 0 0 1 1.5.6" />
  <line id="hand" stroke="black" stroke-width=".02" x1="1.5" y1="1.7" x2="1.5" y2=".2" />
</svg>
```

Comment: In case you're wondering where the coefficient `0.01309` came from — this converts the angle (in degrees) to the path length along a circle of radius 0.75 (2 * π * 0.75 / 360 ≈ 0.01309)

Comment: gotcha: some browsers (think it is old safari iOs) don't start a circle at 90 degrees. solution: convert circle to path.

Comment: @squeamishossifrage That looks like it's going to work. I recall now that I had seen a description of the masking solution but I thought the math shouldn't be too hard. But I think this will work well. Thanks.